# Entity Framework 4: Update Single Record

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've got a Method that has a Model "Address" as a parameter.

Now inside this method I want to "overwrite" my existing Address in the Database with the provided address - just like updating it in SQL.

I do the inserting-bit like this:

```
            Context.Addresses.AddObject(adr);
            Context.SaveChanges();
```

How do I do the updating-part?

I've tried something like this:

```
   public void Update(Address adr)
   {
            Context.Addresses.Attach(adr);
            Context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Sadly, this does not work... I've also tried plenty of other codes, but none of them worked.

So how can I update an existing record in my DB when I get an object of the modified record as a parameter?

Thank you

Comment: Easiest would be to retrieve the existing address, then use `ModelCopier` or `AutoMapper` to update it with the new values, then call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: What's _ModelCopier_ or _AutoMapper_?

Comment: See [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) and a note about [ModelCopier](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/31/easy-way-to-update-models-in-your-asp-net-mvc-business-layer.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update an entity in Entity Framework 4 .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594515/how-to-update-an-entity-in-entity-framework-4-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell EF that the entity is updated by calling [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx)

```
 public void Update(Address adr)
 {
        Context.Addresses.ApplyCurrentValues(adr);

        Context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: This does not work. I can't remember the exact exception, but it says something like "ObjectManager can't manage more than one object with the same KeyField" or something like that.

Comment: @SeToY Then use [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx) method as shown in updated answer

Comment: This results in: "An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of the supplied object match the key values of the object to which changes must be applied." When I first call context.Attach(adr), no exception occurs but it doesn't update the row in the db

Comment: @SeToY Check whether an istance with same PK is tracked by the context. If so use `ApplyCurrentValues`. Otherwise Attach the new instance and set its state as `Modified`.